# list of objects (blocks for network)

Tags: networking, openstack, terraform

In [`openstack_compute_instance_v2`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/openstack/r/compute_instance_v2.html), Terraform can attach the existing networks, while I have 1 or n network to attach, in module:

```
...

variable "vm_network" {
  type = "list"  
} 


resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "singlevm" {
    name            = "${var.vm_name}"
    image_id        = "${var.vm_image}"
    key_pair        = "${var.vm_keypair}"
    security_groups = "${var.vm_sg}"
    flavor_name     = "${var.vm_size}"
    network  = "${var.vm_network}"
}
```

in my `.tf` file:

```
module "singlevm" {
    ...
    vm_network = {"name"="NETWORK1"}
    vm_network = {"name"="NETWORK2"}
}
```

Terraform returns `expected object, got invalid` error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you specify a list in your `.tf` file that sources the module.

Instead you should have something more like:

```
variable "vm_network" { default = [ "NETWORK1", "NETWORK2" ] }

module "singlevm" {
    ...
    vm_network = "${var.vm_network}"
}
```

Comment: don't think your approach work, since the NETWORK1 only is the name of network. Network consists name, access ... etc., multiple attributes.